# Keyboard half working

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I have trouble with the keyboard on windows 7 Home edition. The "main" keyboard doesn't work only extra (useless) keys work.Such as the email key, media player key and such. I can't do a system recovery. I checked my hardware manager there are warning sign on both keyboard and mouse (the mouse seems to work fine though). No driver repair/update seem to work. I tried Microsoft "fix it" tools and it only tells me there is trouble but can't solve anything. I tied a new keyboard  too; no changes. Is there a solution other than formatting and re-installing windows?

Comment: By "main" keyboard, do you mean you have more than one and if so, is more than one connected to the computer?  Have you tried using a different keyboard and does that work?  Have you tried using a keyboard with a different interface (PS2 vs. USB)?  Did it previously work and suddenly stopped?

Comment: By "main" I meant the alphabet, the numbers and so on. But problem solve I uninstalled and re-installed avast. The trouble came from it.

Comment: Can you please post this as a solution, then mark it solved? Otherwise people will keep looking at this solution trying to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solve I uninstalled and re-installed avast. The trouble came from it.